# I can't download images uploaded with "move_uploaded_file()" code on filezilla

Tags: php, html, image, move

When I use `move_uploaded_file()` code everything works fine and my files are being moved to my server. But later if I want to download those files from my server using filezilla, it says:

> "Could not start the transfer process"

But I can download other files crate with `imagejpeg()` code. So what is the problem?

Comment: Seems to be a permission problem. Are there any differences in the permissions or directories between the files created by `move_uploaded_file` and `imagejpeg`?

Comment: all file permissions are "xxx" on my server on filezilla

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you rename one of the files which does not works for download to `test.jpg` to `test.gif` (assuming that `jpg` are not working).

If it does not work.. Check the permission for read and writes in your control panel for **ftp user**

Comment: 550 Access is denied. i couldn't rename.

Comment: Then access is denied by admin. You are allowed to download only files that you have been uploaded. That's why you cannot download files upload via PHP. Then change your access permission in control panel or ask the provider to change it...

Comment: thanks. you right, problem was my writing permissions. i have fixed my problem and its done.